# How can I paginate my table and search trough everything at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, element-ui

I have an overview table wehere I list all my elements.
But I paginate them so that just 10 elements will be showed.

My table looks like that:

```
<el-table
  :data="paginatedData.filter(data => !search || data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))"
  border
  fit
  highlight-current-row>
  <!-- table content -->
</el-table>
```

Basically paginatedData includes 10 elements.
The variable "tools" includes all available elements.

I want to keep the pagination but at the same time I need to search through every element of tools, not just the 10 of my paginatedData.

So I tried to change it to:

```
<el-table
  :data="paginatedData.filter(tools => !search || tools.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))"
  border
  fit
  highlight-current-row>
  <!-- table content -->
</el-table>
```

I guess I just have some problems to find the right Syntax to solve my problem.

Hope you guys have an idea...

Answer (score 2):

There are three levels of data in this example:

1. The unfiltered data set;
2. The data set that has been filtered according to your search term (assuming a search term is being used, otherwise this will be equal to the unfiltered data set); and
3. The paginated data, which you wish to be split into packages of ten entries each.

This suggests you should use four variables:

1. `const data`: an array of objects with at least one property, `tool_name`
2. `let filteredData`: a subset of the above, filtered such that `tool_name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()`
3. `let currentPageData`: a subset of filtered data where the index of the items corresponds to the current page, i.e. page 1 = entries with index 0-9, page 2 = entries with index 10-19 etc.
4. `let currentPage: number` a variable which stores the current page.

On your initial page load, you want to initialise currentPage to 1. The logic to populate the table is therefore:

```html
<el-table
  :data="currentPageData"
  border
  fit
  highlight-current-row>
  <!-- table content -->
</el-table>
```

Where

```
filteredData = !search ? data : data.filter((entry) => entry.tool_name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase())
currentPageData = filteredData.filter((entry, index) => (index < (currentPage * 10) - 1 && index > ((currentPage - 1) * 10)))
```

i.e. if there is a search your filtered data is filtered according to it, otherwise filteredData is just set to data. currentPageData then uses the currentPage variable to extract the ten entries corresponding to the current page selected. I'm assuming you can handle how to add buttons to your table to select different pages.

Clearly this is not a fully working solution but should give some idea how to implement one.